# regular expression for find and replace

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've got strings like:

`('Michael Herold','Michael Herold'),`

but I need to remove the last parts so I end up with:

`('Michael Herold'),`

I'm still new to Regular Expressions so they confuse me. I'm using Notepad++.

Comment: Can you give us a few more examples? Does the second string always have to be `Michael Herold`, or does it always need to equal the first string? It's a little unclear if `('Michael Herold','Not Michael Herold'),` should be changed, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find: \('([^']*)','\1'\) 
Replace: ('\1')
```

Answer (score 0):

So the actual function you use will depend on the language. Notepad++ is a text editor, not a language.

The regular expression that you will want will be ",'Michael Herold'" and you'll replace any matches with "", the empty string.

So in PHP for example, you'll have

```
    $source = "('Michael Herold','Michael Herold')";
    $pattern = "/(,'Michael Herold')+/";
    $newString = $preg_replace($pattern, $source, "");
```

Do the equivalent in whatever language you use.

Comment: This will match `('Not Michael Herold','Michael Herold'),`, `('Michael Herold','Michael Herold','Michael Herold'),`, etc. I can't say for sure that this isn't what OP wanted, but I just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what flavor of regular expressions Notepad++ uses, but try replacing this expression:

`\('([^']*)','\1'\)`

with this one:

`('$1')`

The `\1` matches whatever was found in the first set of single quotes (`Michael Herold` in your example), and `$1` is replaced with that same string. (Try `\1` if `$1` doesn't work in Notepad++.)

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?2u7hn).